# c#  Linq's -  GroupedEnumerable usages?

Tags: c#, linq, .net-4.0, ienumerable

```
 Fruit[] data = new[] {
                new Fruit {Name = "Gala",Type = "Apple",Price = 0.75m,Quantity = 10}, 
                new Fruit {Name = "Granny Smith",Type = "Apple",Price = 0.80m,Quantity = 7},
                new Fruit {Name = "Tasty",Type = "Strawberries",Price = 1.90m,Quantity = 20}
                       };

 var grouped = from fruit in data
                          group fruit by fruit.Type;
```

`grouped` type is : `System.Linq.GroupedEnumerable<ConsoleApplication15.Fruit,string,ConsoleApplication15.Fruit>`

have a look on it : [image]

my question  :

if grouped contains items ( implements ienumerable ) - why its  type is `GroupedEnumerable`

and **not**

```
IEnumerable <System.Linq.IGrouping<string,ConsoleApplication15.Fruit>>
```

why did they create a new Type aka `GroupedEnumerable` ?

Comment: That's simple: an object has to be some concrete type, it can't be just an interface.

Comment: @svick i dont follow you... more than 1 senctence will be much appreciated. :)

Comment: @svick i dont HAVE TO iterating through object.. i can also iterate though interface....

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you have an *object* in .Net, it has to be of some concrete type, it can't be an interface. So, for example, `new IList<int>()` is not valid, you have to do something like `new List<int>()`.

If you have a *variable*, its type can be an interface, so you can write, for example, `IList<int> list = new List<int>()`.

And that's exactly what's happening here. The type of the *variable* `grouped` is `IEnumerable<IGrouping<string,Fruit>>` (although it's not clear from the code, because you're using `var`). The type of the *object* referenced by that variable is `GroupedEnumerable<Fruit, string, Fruit>`, which is an internal type used by the implementation of `GroupBy()`. It can't be `IEnumerable`, because you can't have an instance of an interface.

The Visual Studio debugger is showing you the runtime type of the object, because that's what debugger is for: to show you the runtime information.

Comment: svick - via resharper  -  when i sttod over the `var` its suggested me to change to explicit type and he changed it to `IEnumerable<IGrouping<string, Fruit>> grouped = from fruit in data
                          group fruit by fruit.Type;`.... so i dont get it - i could use both....same as ilist and list...why is that ?

Comment: The code that uses `IEnumerable` is exactly the same as the one that uses `var`, because that's what the return type of the query. You couldn't use `GroupedEnumerable`, because it's internal. But I'm not sure what exactly don't you get.

Comment: hi thanks for replying.. can i conclude that  " the access to the object is via an interface , but i can not access via interface - to another interface , i must have some concrete class " ?