# MVC 4 IEnumerable<IGrouping<int32, model>> to view

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, view, controller, ienumerable, igrouping

How to I get the grouped data to show up on my view? 
It wants to recieve a IEnumerable of the model but I'm passing grouped data.

I'm returning this to the view in my controller:

```
var slb = (from s in db.Tbl_Slb
          group s by s.Tbl_Docent.Docent_Code into d
          select d)
```

This is the model

```
public partial class Tbl_Slb
    {
        public Tbl_Slb()
        {
            this.Tbl_Opmerking = new HashSet<Tbl_Opmerking>();
        }

        public System.DateTime Slb_Van { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> Slb_Tot { get; set; }
        public string Student_Nummer { get; set; }
        public int Docent_Code { get; set; }
        public int Slb_Code { get; set; }

        public virtual Tbl_Docent Tbl_Docent { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Tbl_Opmerking> Tbl_Opmerking { get; set; }
        public virtual Tbl_Student Tbl_Student { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: then shouldn't your view be taking in a type of IEnumerable<Tbl_Slb> and dont really want to stick my nose in but Tbl_Slb,  Slb_Van, Slb_Tot   is going to be a nightmare for anyone else that may have to work on that code, and try like hell to work out what all the abbreviations stand for

Comment: Actually those aren't abbreviations, they're dutch.
And yes the view takes an IEnumerable<Tbl_Slb>

Comment: if your query returns results, and the problem is with your view, then maybe you would be better showing the view too so we can see the whole process?

Comment: the query does return results but it returns IGroupings instead of IEnumerables. I want to know how to interpret those on my view.
The View is nothing special mostly default.

Comment: maybe this is a related question posted on SO http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10461882/c-sharp-linqs-groupedenumerable-usages